# Added sub nav to off canvas navigation and now the sub menu headers and menus are showing when the menu is closed

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been adapting an existing off canvas design and have hit a brick wall. I have added sub menus and now they are showing when the menu is closed. I am guessing it is a positioning issue but after looking at it for a few days I can't figure it out. It is also worth noting that the issue only appears when the view-port is small enough for the media queries to be activated. Here is the code:

Here is a working example of the site with the issue [example](http://www.ashleybriscoe.com). **I tried to create a fiddle but it wouldn't function correctly.** View in Chrome to see the issue and resize the browser to see the off canvas menu issue.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>some site</title>

    <script src="js/plugins/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!--[if (gt IE 8) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="outer-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">

    <header id="top" role="banner">
        <div class="block">
            <h1 class="block-title">TEST</h1>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#main-nav">Main Menu</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="block-title">Main menu</h2>
             <ul>
                <li class="is-active">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a class="toggle-sub-nav closed" href="#">Link</a>
                      <ul class="sub-nav">
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li class="is-active"><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a class="toggle-sub-nav closed" href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sub link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="close-btn" id="nav-close-btn" href="#top">Return to Content</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section id="main" role="main">
        <article class="block prose">

     <h1>Some content NEW30</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

        <p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. </p>

        <p>Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. </p>

        <p>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. </p>

       <p>Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>
        </article>
    </section>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <div class="block prose">
            <p class="small">Copyright © <a href="http://ashleybriscoe.com/">Some author</a></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div><!--/#inner-wrap-->

</div><!--/#outer-wrap-->

</body>

<script src="js/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/scripts/main.js"></script>

<script src="js/plugins/jquery.hammer.min.js"></script>

<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/selectivizr.js"></script>

<![endif]-->

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 20em;
  background: #7C9769;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5em 1.25em;
  max-width: 60em;

}

.close-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #7C9769 url("../assets/img/close-btn.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.875em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .close-btn {
  background-image: url("../assets/img/close-btn.png");
}
.close-btn:focus, .close-btn:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #7C9769 url("../assets/img/nav-icon.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .nav-btn {
  background-image: url("../assets/img/nav-icon.png");
}
.nav-btn:hover, .nav-btn:focus {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

#outer-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-nav {
  z-index: 200;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
#main-nav .close-btn {
  display: none;
}
#main-nav .block-title {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
#main-nav .block {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
  background: #7C9769;
}
#main-nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
  display: block;
}
#main-nav ul:before, #main-nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#main-nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#main-nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 11em;

}
#main-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #365239;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.28571em;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;

}



#main-nav li a:focus, #main-nav li a:hover {

  color: #EEE;

}
#main-nav li.is-active a {

  color: #EEE;

}


#main-nav li ul li { float: left; border-right: none;}

#main-nav li ul li a:focus, #main-nav li ul li a:hover {

  color: #7C9769;

}

#main-nav li ul li.is-active a {

     color: #7C9769;
}

 .js .sub-nav {

    height: 0;
    width: 11em;
    background-color:#E4E1E1;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;

}

  .js .sub-nav-open {

    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    top: 52px;

    }

 .no-js #main-nav li ul.sub-nav {

    display: none;
    width: 11em;
    background-color:#E4E1E1;

}

.no-js #main-nav li:hover ul.sub-nav {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: solid 11px #7C9769;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 2000;

    }

.closed { background: url(../assets/img/arrows.png) no-repeat 90% -28px; }

.open { background: url(../assets/img/arrows.png) no-repeat 90% 9px; }


#top {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: #7C9769;
}
#top .block-title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: wrap;
}
#top .nav-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.7em;
  left: 1.875em;
}

#main {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer[role="contentinfo"] {
  background: #ddd;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 45.0625em) {
  #top .nav-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  #main-nav .close-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #main-nav .block-title {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #main-nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  #main-nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #main-nav li a {
    padding: 0.42857em 0.85714em;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {

  #main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 4.5em;
  }
  #main-nav:not(:target) {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
  }
  #main-nav:target .close-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  #main-nav .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3.75em;
    left: 1.875em;
  }
  #main-nav .block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #main-nav li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main-nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #main-nav li.is-active:after {
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -0.03125em;
    margin-top: -0.625em;
    border-top: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-right: 0.625em white solid;
  }
  #main-nav li a {
    padding: 0.85714em 2.14286em;
  }

 .js .sub-nav {

    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#E4E1E1;
    overflow:hidden;

}

  .js .sub-nav-open {

    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px; 
    top: 0;
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;

    }

 .no-js #main-nav li ul.sub-nav {

    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#E4E1E1;

}

.no-js #main-nav li:hover ul.sub-nav {

    display: block;
    top: 52px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    border-top:none;
    }

.closed { background: url(../assets/img/arrows.png) no-repeat 95% -24px; }

.open { background: url(../assets/img/arrows.png) no-repeat 95% 13px; }

    #main-nav li ul li {

    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  #main-nav li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }



  .js-ready #main-nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    background: #7C9769;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  .js-ready #main-nav .block {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .js-ready #main-nav .close-btn {
    display: block;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .js-ready #main-nav .close-btn:focus, .js-ready #main-nav .close-btn:hover {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .js-ready #main-nav {
    left: -70%;
  }
  .js-ready #inner-wrap {
    left: 0;
  }

  .js-nav #inner-wrap {
    left: 70%;
  }

  .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #main-nav {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #inner-wrap {
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-nav #inner-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -o-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #main-nav .block {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms 100ms, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: ease, 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms 100ms ease, -moz-transform 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms 100ms ease, -o-transform 500ms ease;
    transition: opacity 300ms 100ms ease, transform 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -o-transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  }

  .csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-nav #main-nav .block {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Here is a screen shot showing the issue in Google Chrome:

[image: Screen shot of menu items showing when menu is closed]

Comment: You should make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or somethink like that

Comment: Okay, I will put one together.

Comment: Unfortunately a fiddle wouldn't work correctly so I have included a live example in my question.

Comment: What browser is this you are using?

Comment: Chrome mobile and desktop

Comment: I can see the issue in firefox and IE11 as well.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and in chrome and firefox I only see the plus signes onverlapping the content but not the grey background.

Comment: If you click om the plus signs the sub menu opens. The issue has been fixed now with the answer below. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following properties to `.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #main-nav .block` this class in media query

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #main-nav .block {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
/*Other styles goes here*/
}
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat thanks. Can you explain what the issue was and why this has fixed this so I can gain a greater understanding of this.

Comment: The issue is because the parent element has `-100px` translate, not for the block, So I just add it to block also.